# How do you format a USB stick after it is being labled "unrecognised" by Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, mkfs

I have a memory stick which I had cleaned of old data fragments.

The memory stick was mounted on /dev/sdc1 so I did:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1M
```

After the task was complete, my usb memory stick became unrecognized.

What do you do in this case to make the drive recognized again and partition it as FAT?

Comment: The "dd" command do not format any partition. It simply write blocks from/to devices. Your command just write zeros to the device of your usb stick partition. This is a easy way to cleanup the whole partition from old datafragments. But it is no formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a filesystem on your usb stick partition, you should do

```
    mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdc1
```

as a user who as access rights to write to the partition, like `root`

Answer (score 2):

Use `parted` (`gparted` if you want a GUI) or `fdisk` to format partitions

Comment: fdisk creates partitions. To create a filesystem (format in DOS/Windows terminology), use `mkfs`.

Answer (score -1):

Use following

```
sudo su
gparted
```

Then select devices from menu,
select usb drive and work....