# USB key not responding when inserted

Tags: usb, usb-drive, dd, live-usb, chrome-os

I just attempted to create a USB key for Chrome OS. I followed the instructions found [here](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/). This is what I did:

1- Downloaded a `.zip` [version of the build](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/download/vanilla?&version=3812.0.2013_03_08_1632-r10c5647c&type=usb).

2- Extracted the `.zip` file which gave me a `.img` file.

3- Tried to burn the `.img` file to the USB key with the following command:

```
dd if=ChromeOS-Vanilla-3812.0.2013_03_08_1632-r10c5647c.img of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4M
```

4- That gave me a *Permission denied* error so I tried:

```
sudo dd if=ChromeOS-Vanilla-3812.0.2013_03_08_1632-r10c5647c.img of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4M
```

which seemed to work (at least it ended with a message that ~2.5Gb had been copied to the device)

But now if I insert the USB key the system does not recognize it anymore. I tried booting my laptop with that USB inserted but it did not pick it up either. Did I just destroy my 16Gb USB key?? Cheers.

---

Update: the *Disk* utility does recognize when the device is inserted. I tried to format the USB key with this app but got the error:

```
Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

---

Update 2: `fdisk` apparently also recognizes the device. The command `sudo fdisk -l` returns:

```
Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sdc1   *          32    31270911    15635440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

(my system is in Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

Ok just fixed it. Found the answer [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/how-do-you-format-a-usb-stick-after-it-is-being-labled-unrecognised-by-ubuntu). I just had to run:

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdc1
```

and the USB key was recognized again.